# opsworks parameters and resources in the cloudformation template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I'm working on a cloudformation template that has many parameters, like the ID of the elastic file system and the DNS of the MountTarget. I want to retreive these parameters from the existing resources, but if they are not already created I want to create them in the template :

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "AWS CloudFormation Template : Stack OpsWorks Slave pour deployer les instances script",


  "Mappings": {

    "Region2Principal": {

      "us-east-1": {
        "EC2Principal": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "OpsWorksPrincipal": "opsworks.amazonaws.com"
      },

      "us-west-2": {
        "EC2Principal": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "OpsWorksPrincipal": "opsworks.amazonaws.com"
      },

      "us-west-1": {
        "EC2Principal": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "OpsWorksPrincipal": "opsworks.amazonaws.com"
      },

      "eu-west-1": {
        "EC2Principal": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "OpsWorksPrincipal": "opsworks.amazonaws.com"
      }
    },

    "AWSInstanceType2Arch" : {

           "t1.micro"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
           "t2.micro"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "m1.small"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
           "m1.large"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
           "m4.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "m4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "m4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "m4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "m4.10xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "m4.16xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "c3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "c3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "c3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "c3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "c3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "c4.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"    },
           "c4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "c4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "c4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
           "c4.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  }
    },

    "AWSRegionArch2AMI" : {

      "us-east-1" : { "PV64" : "ami-5fb8c835", "HVM64" : "ami-60b6c60a" },
      "us-west-1" : { "PV64" : "ami-56ea8636", "HVM64" : "ami-d5ea86b5" },
      "eu-west-1" : { "PV64" : "ami-95e33ce6", "HVM64" : "ami-bff32ccc" },
      "us-west-2" : { "PV64" : "ami-d93622b8", "HVM64" : "ami-f0091d91" }
    }

  },


  "Parameters": {

    "OpsWorksStackColor": {
        "Description": "RGB Color to use for OpsWorks Stack",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "rgb(38, 146, 168)"
    },

    "Region" : {
        "Type":"String",
        "Description": "Region location of the template resources",
        "Default": "eu-west-1",
        "AllowedValues" : [ "us-east-1", "us-west-1", "us-west-2", "eu-west-1" ]
    },

    "SecurityGroupIds": {
        "Description": "Security groups that can be used to access the EC2 instances, do not select more than 5 SG",
        "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>",
        "ConstraintDescription": "must be list of EC2 security group ids"
    },

    "VpcId": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
        "Description": "VPC associated with the provided subnets",
        "Default": "vpc-69e3320c",
        "ConstraintDescription": "must be an existing VPC ID"
    },

    "SubnetId": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "subnet-6820eb31",
        "ConstraintDescription": "must be an existing subnet ID"
    },

    "InstanceType": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "c3.large",
        "AllowedValues" : ["t2.micro", "m1.small", "m1.large","m4.large","m4.xlarge","m4.2xlarge","m4.4xlarge","m4.10xlarge","m4.16xlarge","c4.large" , "c4.xlarge" ,"c4.2xlarge" , "c4.4xlarge","c4.8xlarge" , "c3.large" , "c3.xlarge", "c3.2xlarge", "c3.4xlarge" ,"c3.8xlarge"],
        "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type"
    },

    "KeyPairName": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
        "Default": "test-generic-ec2",
        "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair"
    },

    "CookbookS3" : {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket.test.cookbooks/cookbook-v1.tar.gz",
        "ConstraintDescription": "the Url to the cookbook"
    },

    "CookbookS3AccessID": {
        "Type": "String",
        "ConstraintDescription": "username to the appropriate IAM access key ID"
    },

    "CookbookS3AccessKey": {
        "Type": "String",
        "NoEcho" : "true",
        "ConstraintDescription": "password to the appropriate IAM secret access key"
    },

    "MountPoint" : {
        "Description" : "The Linux mount point for the EFS volume",
        "Type": "String",
        "MinLength": "1",
        "Default": "efs-file-appli-tmp"
    },

    "MountPointDNS" : {
        "Description" : "Mount target DNS name",
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default" : "eu-west-1a.fs-c2388dc0b.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    },

    "FileSystem" : {
        "Description" :"The Id of the FileSystem",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "fs-c2388dc0b"
    },

    "NewRelicLicence" : {
        "Description": "The licence key of newrelic",
        "Type": "String"
    },

    "Environnement" : {
        "Description": "The Environnement variable ",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "test",
        "AllowedValues" : ["dev", "test", "int", "prod"]
    }

  },

  "Conditions" : {
    "CreateProdResources" : { "Fn::Not" : [{  "Fn::Equals" : [ {"Ref" : "Environnement"},"test" ] }] }
  },

  "Resources": {

    "MyStack": {
        "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Stack",
        "Properties": {
         "AgentVersion" : "LATEST",
         "Name": { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
         "Attributes": { "Color": { "Ref": "OpsWorksStackColor" } },
         "ChefConfiguration": {},
         "ConfigurationManager": { "Name": "Chef", "Version": "12" },
         "CustomCookbooksSource": {
           "Type": "s3",
           "Password" : { "Ref": "CookbookS3AccessKey" },
           "Username" : { "Ref": "CookbookS3AccessID" },
           "Url": { "Ref": "CookbookS3" }
         },
         "CustomJson":  { 

                          "mount" : { "mountdir" : {
                            "default" : { "dirname" : { "Ref" : "MountPoint" } } }
                          },
                          "mountadd" : { "mountdns" : {
                            "default" : { "mdns" : { "Ref" : "MountPointDNS" }}}
                          }


         },
         "DefaultInstanceProfileArn": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "OpsWorksInstanceProfile","Arn" ] },
         "DefaultOs": "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS",
         "DefaultRootDeviceType": "ebs",
         "DefaultSshKeyName": { "Ref": "KeyPairName" },
         "DefaultSubnetId" : {"Ref" : "SubnetId" },
         "ServiceRoleArn": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["OpsWorksServiceRole", "Arn"] },
         "UseCustomCookbooks": true,
         "UseOpsworksSecurityGroups" : true,
         "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" }
        }
    },

    "MyLayer": {
        "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Layer",
        "DependsOn" : "OpsWorksServiceRole",
        "Properties": {
         "AutoAssignElasticIps" : false,
         "AutoAssignPublicIps" : true,
         "CustomRecipes" : {
           "Setup"     : ["cassandra-php-driver::setup","awscli::setup","crontab::setup","prometheus-server::setup","awslogs::setup","newrelic::php_agent","settings::setup"],
           "Configure" : ["cassandra-php-driver::configure","security::configure","settings::default"],
           "Deploy": ["imports::deploy"]
        },
         "CustomSecurityGroupIds" : { "Ref" : "SecurityGroupIds" },
         "EnableAutoHealing" : true,
         "InstallUpdatesOnBoot": false,
         "LifecycleEventConfiguration": {
           "ShutdownEventConfiguration": {
           "DelayUntilElbConnectionsDrained": false,
           "ExecutionTimeout": 120 }
         },
         "Name": "script-node",
         "Shortname" : "node",
         "StackId": { "Ref": "MyStack" },
         "Type": "custom",
         "UseEbsOptimizedInstances": true,
         "VolumeConfigurations": [ {
           "Iops": 10000,
           "MountPoint": "/dev/sda1",
           "NumberOfDisks": 1,
           "Size": 20,
           "VolumeType": "gp2"
         }]
      }
    },

    "OpsWorksServiceRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
         "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version" : "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [ {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": { "Service": [ { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "Region2Principal",{ "Ref": "AWS::Region" },"OpsWorksPrincipal" ] } ] },
                             "Action" : [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
          } ]
            },
         "Path": "/",
         "Policies": [ {
          "PolicyName": "opsworks-service",
          "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version" : "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [ {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
            } ]
          }
          } ]
        }
    },

    "OpsWorksInstanceRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
         "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version" : "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [ {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": { "Service" : [ { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "Region2Principal", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },"EC2Principal" ] } ] },
                             "Action"  : [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
          }]
         },
         "Path": "/",
         "Policies": [{
          "PolicyName": "aws-opsworks-instance",
          "PolicyDocument": {
            "Statement": [{
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "*",
              "Resource": "*"
            }]
          }
         }]
        }
    },

    "OpsWorksInstanceProfile": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
        "Properties": {
         "Path": "/",
         "Roles": [ { "Ref": "OpsWorksInstanceRole" } ]
      }
    },

    "MyInstance": {
        "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Instance",
        "Properties": {
         "Hostname": "Script",
         "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
         "StackId": {"Ref": "MyStack"},
         "LayerIds": [{"Ref": "MyLayer"}],
         "InstanceType": {"Ref" : "InstanceType"}
        }
    },

    "MyApp": {
        "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::App",
        "Properties": {
         "AppSource" : {
          "Type" : "git",
          "Url" : "git://github.com:globlW/My-imports.git",
          "Revision" : "develop"
         },
         "Description": "Dataimport and connectors",
         "Name" : "app-Imports",
         "Shortname" : "app_imports",
         "StackId" : {"Ref": "MyStack"},
         "Type" : "other"
        }
    },

    "MyFileSystem" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EFS::FileSystem",
        "Condition" : "CreateProdResources",
        "Properties" : {
         "FileSystemTags" : [{
          "Key" : "Name",
          "Value" : {"Ref" : "MountPoint"}
         }]
        }
    },

    "MountTarget": {
        "Type": "AWS::EFS::MountTarget",
        "Condition" : "CreateProdResources",
        "Properties": {
         "FileSystemId": { "Ref": "MyFileSystem" },
          "SubnetId": { "Ref": "SubnetId" },
          "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "SecurityGroupIds" } ]
        }
    }

  }




}
```

As you see, I use often the `{ "Ref" : "FileSystem" }`  , `{ "Ref" : "MountPointDNS" }` and  `{ "Ref" : "MountPoint" }`, I specially need them in the CustomJson. The problem is how to link the parameters with the recent created resources and how to name them ? can I give the same name so that I can always get a value to customjson ?
I hope my issue is clear. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to conditionally use an existing resource using [Condition Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html). See the [Conditionally use an existing resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-sample-templates.html#d0e163820) example in the documentation, which demonstrates the following pattern:

```
Parameters: 
  ExistingResource: 
    Description: An existing resource (optional).
    Default: NONE
    Type: String
Conditions: 
  CreateNewResource: !Equals [!Ref ExistingResource, NONE]
Resources: 
  NewResource:
    Condition: CreateNewResource
    Type: # Resource type
    Properties: # Resource properties
Outputs:
  ResourceId:
    Description: Reference to either a newly-created or existing resource.
    Value: !If [CreateNewResource, !Ref NewResource, !Ref ExistingResource]
```